# How to format the duration of YouTube API video using moment.js

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, momentjs

I write a small feature to search videos in YouTube with YouTube API v3

The format of video duration like `PT2M54S`
I would like to convert it as `00:02:54` use `moment.js`

Have any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [`moment.duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) object and then format it using [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in. The library adds `format` method to durations and has the [`trim`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/blob/master/README.md#trim) option that lets you get the output in the format you asked.

A sample code is the following:

```js
var dur = moment.duration('PT2M54S');
console.log( dur.format('HH:mm:ss', {trim: false}) ); // 00:02:54
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm recreating the YouTube iOS app and use [moment](http://momentjs.com) + [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) to create the running times in the bottom corner of a video (e.g. 4:05).

If you're interested in that, I offer this utility function:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';

export default (duration) => moment
    .duration(duration)
    .format('h:mm:ss')
    .padStart(4, '0:0');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method returns the duration in seconds. So you could simply use that in moment.js

```
function getDurationInSecond(youtubeDuration)
{
    var re=/pt([0-9]+)M([0-9]+)S/gi,
        rex = new RegExp(re),
        du = rex.exec(youtubeDuration);
    if (du.length<1)
        return 0;
    var s=0;
    s+= du.length >1 && du[1]? parseInt(du[1], 10) * 60 :0; // adding minute
    s+= du.length >2 && du[2]? parseInt(du[1], 10) :0; //
    return s;
}

var time='PT2M45S';
console.log(getDurationInSecond(time));
```

Comment: does not work if duration is "PT5S"